# open link in IE browser in 100% zoom level

Tags: internet-explorer, url, parameters

cay anyone know how do I force IE to show a specific link in zoom level: 100%

maybe to send parameters in the url bar:

http://somesite.com/?zoom=100

thank you,
Mor

Answer (score 1):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms531189(v=vs.85).aspx

> "Windows Internet Explorer 8. The
>   -ms-zoom attribute is an extension to CSS, and can be used as a synonym for
>   zoom in IE8 mode."

I know this works in IE 8, are you using a different version of IE?